# Scrolling to an item in a list

Tags: jquery, scroll, focus, scrollbar

I have a list of elements I would like to be able to have brought into focus when the user is selecting items. I've tried calling .focus() with Jquery on these objects to no avail. Is there anything I'm missing? :)

EDIT:
I have a list (ul) of elements. I shift click on a starting item and and press the arrow keys to continue selecting. Up and down. I would really like for the shift selection to function as if it was in Finder or Windows Explorer. Scrolling up when an item is selected that's not visible (and down for the same case).

Are there any handy jQuery plugins to handle this for me?

EDIT2:
Figured out some things and determined a larger problem.

Right now I am using the jQuery plugin called scrollTo. I can scroll to an element of my list using this plugin. However, "scrolling" to an item means it is now the first item in the list, which is NOT desirable behavior. Select any number of items in Finder or Explorer and see that when you shift-arrow select an item that's offscreen, it only scrolls down one item's worth of space and does NOT make it the top element.

Easy to fix of course. ;) I am currently keeping track of the current element just off screen on the top and the current element in the list that's just offscreen on the bottom. However, when the user selects an item out of the list after they have done some scrolling, I currently have no way to tell what elements are just out of sight, creating an impasse.

Any ideas? :P

Comment: Its not really clear as to what you want, can you post in some html that you are trying to work with ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear from your question, but if you're talking about automatically scrolling the page (or element) so that a particular element is in the viewport, you might try the [scrollTo plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo).

```
$.scrollTo('#something'); // scrolls the whole page so #something is in view
$('#mydiv').scrollTo('#somethingelse'); // scrolls the (scrollable) div
```

**Edit:** Your question update provides a *little* more insight into what you're looking for. I'm not clear on what method you're using to achieve the shift-selection (or if you're actually expanding the question to ask how to do that). But assuming you're still just asking about the scrolling piece, I would add the scrolling call in a function attached to whichever event (custom?) is fired when you add another list item to your selection.

For example, assuming you're triggering a custom event called `list_expanded` each time an `<li>` is selected, you could try something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('ul#mylist').delegate('li','list_expanded', function(){
    $(this).scrollTo();
  });
});
```

Obviously you can also use a "regular" event like `click`, depending on how your multiple-select solution works.

Comment: Many thanks for this. Any advice on what to use for setting an ID on the fly? I want to see an ID to a certain element, scroll to that element and then unset the id.

Comment: How do you know which element you want to scroll to? There's no point in setting and unsetting an ID, since you'd first have to identify the element to which you'd apply the ID. You can use any jQuery selection method to identify the element.

Comment: I have an index of where in the list I want to scroll to. I am trying to use children to get the element but it's not working of course. :P

Comment: @bobber, please update your question with the code you're using, plus a reduced example of the html, and I'll update my answer with something more specific.

Comment: Updated with the progress I've made and a new but related issue.

Comment: @bobber, a picture is worth a thousand words. Can you post a working page somewhere, reduced to show this specific issue?